# Should I seal western red cedar post ends?

Tags: pergola, sealer, cedar

Building an 8x8x8 pergula using TojaGrid brackets, which encase the ends of posts. Never worked with cedar before. Located in NE Ohio, which gets a lot of rain and snow.

Bought the 4x4 cedar new last week. Water drip tested the sides of posts, and water sits on, does not soak in.

Should I use an end sealer, and if so which type?

Should I add some type of sealer to the sides of posts, given they're not absorbing much currently? Which type? I've heard linseed oil is good. Have Thompsons water seal on hand.

Comment: Are you using standoffs (post base connections that raise the timber above the ground)? End sealer doesn't give enough protection on its own against timber sitting directly in contact with the rot driving ground

Comment: @LukeBriggs - there's an 1/8" lip around the base of the post bracket, but it doesn't cover the entire width of the post end. So post won't be in direct contact with the concrete, but I would expect water to get under.

Comment: Do you want the pergola to age to a gray color, or will you seal the structure to keep its natural color? The reason I ask, I would put the Thompsons in a 5 gallon bucket and set the posts in the bucket to soak up the sealer for a day or 2. If it gets too far up the posts and you want it to age, it will look weird if the sealer gets too high on the posts. It should only take a few inches of treatment to work. The most important part is sealing the end grain. Cedar is not so prone to rot as it is. But with the right circumstances it will in time.

Comment: @Jack - thanks, I would like to retain (or enhance) the color, so should I Thompsons the entire surface area, even if it's not that absorbent now?

Comment: The question was pertaining how neat the dipping/soaking needed to be. If it is going to be finished with Thompsons, it won't matter then. About the lack of absorbency, cedar should soak that stuff in readily.... Is the wood really wet? if so, you need to be patient and let it dry for a few weeks. It takes a long time for any considerable moisture loss to occur.